# How to pass comma-separated values passed as string parameter to an Oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure in Oracle in which I am passing string value in `myString` whose value is like (`'xxx','yyy'`) as `varchar` and returning a cursor. My procedure looks like as below:

```
create or replace getName (in_myString in varchar, Name_list out refcursor) IS
Begin
    Open cursor for 
       Select Colunm1 from table where columnName in (in_MyString);
```

But is not returning any records but I am trying to run the query alone it is returning the records. Please can anyone help me?

Comment: The IN clause takes a list of values.  You pass a single string, it will compare `coulunmName` [sic] with the value in `in_myString` verbatim.  You would need dynamic SQL plus splitting the string appropriately to do more or less what you need to do, assuming Oracle supports all that.  I don't know what the standard workaround is in Oracle.  In other DBMS, one technique is to load the list of values into a temporary table and do a join between that and the production table to choose the values.  There may be other ways to do it in Oracle.

Comment: Cursor looks fine, are you passing 'in_myString' variable in proper format? And how do you check that no rows are returned?

Comment: @lokesh I am not sure what should be the format for this type of parameters in Oracle, but when I am passing in_myString value like (xxx), it is returning me one record but when I am passing in_myString value as (xxx,yyy) which is comma separated it is not returning anything

Comment: just a bit of critique, but it sounds like you're not really using sql the best way (storing lists?)

Comment: @user970500: You said in your post "But is not returning any records", how do you check this? Are you printing anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your input value for the parameter is like this  in_myString := 'xxx,yyy'; we can use SQL regular expression functions to split your values based on comma and pass the result list to IN clause.

```
 create or relace getName( in_myString in varchar, Name_list out refcursor)      IS

  Begin

 Open cursor for 
      Select Colunm1 from table where columnName in
          (select regexp_substr(in_myString,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
             connect by regexp_substr(in_myString, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
```

More info on regular expression can be found [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/regular-expressions-support-in-oracle.php).

Comment: I tried this but it seemz regexp_substr is not there in Oracle.. because it says invalid identifier.

Comment: Regular expression functions are introduced in Oracle with 10g version . Refer to link for more info http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/regular-expressions-support-in-oracle.php